# Views filter handler for user authored from Custom Form

Tags: views, 8, users, forms

How can I make a custom views filter handler to filter a list of users which the current user created?

For example: The user adds members to the site a view will show only the members that the user added.

In views, there is a relationship for sorting content based on the current user "Content authored" which is similar.

[image]

Comment: You can't because there is no such field in the user table. So first you need to create this field and fill it with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by 4k4 there is no user authored data in the tables, so I thought I would add what I did to output a view of users the author created.

For me, I needed to do some of this in my custom module you might be able to do this in the configuration if your use case is easier.

```
 1. Create user reference field in /admin/config/people/accounts/fields
 2. Install https://www.drupal.org/project/cer/
 3. Add a corresponding reference in /admin/config/content/cer for your field and the user entity.
 4. Create a relationship for your view from the user field.
 5. Output your view as a block list on your user account page.
```

Now when a user creates a reference the view will shorten to a list of your users.

I took this a step further and created a custom form module to register a user and in code populate the user entity reference field with a form submit for the current user's id. This bit took me a while to work out so hope this helps someone else. :)

```
$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
$uid = $userCurrent->id();
$user->set("field_your_field_name",$uid);
```